# Change state from reducer upon DELETE request responding with empty body

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making a delete request that returns an empty body, what it does is remove an element from an array, how would I know from the reducer which element was removed, since in only recives the state and the response.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `reducer`, `action-creator` and the data you would like to manipulate so we can debug

Comment: the `DELETE_REQUEST` action should have a `deletedId` in the payload so you can remove in the reducer

Comment: @KareemElbahrawy I undertand now, thanks.